# Reindex dataframe multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I've a dataframe with row and column multiindex like this

```
            BLUB      BLA     
            A    B    C    D
sample
0      blub ...  ...
1      blub ...
2      blub
3      blub
4      blub
0      blub
1      blub
2      blub
...    ...
```

I'd like to reindex to this

```
            BLUB      BLA     
            A    B    C    D
sample
0      blub ...  ...
1      blub ...
2      blub
3      blub
4      blub
5      blub
6      blub
7      blub
...    ...
```

in a immutable manner (copying the dataframe, not changing it in place). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some data? Because hard understand `copying the dataframe, not changing it in place`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MultiIndex in index` you can create default index by first level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (df.reset_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .set_index('level_1', append=True)
        .rename_axis(['sample', None]))
```

Or by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(len(df)), 
                                 df.index.get_level_values(1)], 
                                names=['sample', None])
df = df.set_index(mux)
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Your first approach mentioned works for me. (I've not tried the second approach.)